# HIVE - ORC read Issue with NULL Decimal Values - java.io.EOFException: Reading BigInteger past EOF

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, orc

I encountered an issue around HIVE when loading an ORC external table with NULLs inside a column that was defined as DECIMAL(31,8). It looks like hive is unable to read the ORC file after loading and can no longer view the records with a NULL inside that field. Other records in the same ORC file can be read fine.

This has only occurred recently and we have made no changes to our HIVE version. Surprisingly previous ORC files that have been loaded into the same table that have NULLs in the DECIMAL field is queriable without issue.

We are using HIVE 1.2.1. The full stack trace spat out by HIVE is below, I've replaced the actual hdfs location with

```
org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Error reading file: <hdfs location>
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.getNextRowSet(SQLOperation.java:352)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.OperationManager.getOperationNextRowSet(OperationManager.java:220)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl.fetchResults(HiveSessionImpl.java:685)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService.fetchResults(CLIService.java:454)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService.FetchResults(ThriftCLIService.java:672)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults.getResult(TCLIService.java:1553)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults.getResult(TCLIService.java:1538)
        at org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction.process(ProcessFunction.java:39)
        at org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor.process(TBaseProcessor.java:39)
        at org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor.process(TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56)
        at org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess.run(TThreadPoolServer.java:285)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Error reading file: <hdfs location>
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getNextRow(FetchOperator.java:507)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.pushRow(FetchOperator.java:414)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask.fetch(FetchTask.java:140)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.getResults(Driver.java:1670)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.getNextRowSet(SQLOperation.java:347)
        ... 13 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error reading file: <hdfs location>
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReaderImpl.next(RecordReaderImpl.java:1051)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcRawRecordMerger$OriginalReaderPair.next(OrcRawRecordMerger.java:263)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcRawRecordMerger.next(OrcRawRecordMerger.java:547)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$1.next(OrcInputFormat.java:1235)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$1.next(OrcInputFormat.java:1219)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$NullKeyRecordReader.next(OrcInputFormat.java:1151)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.OrcInputFormat$NullKeyRecordReader.next(OrcInputFormat.java:1137)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator.getNextRow(FetchOperator.java:474)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: Reading BigInteger past EOF from compressed stream Stream for column 6 kind DATA position: 201 length: 201 range: 0 offset: 289 limit: 289 range 0 = 0 to 201 uncompressed: 362 to 362
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.SerializationUtils.readBigInteger(SerializationUtils.java:176)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.TreeReaderFactory$DecimalTreeReader.next(TreeReaderFactory.java:1264)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.TreeReaderFactory$StructTreeReader.next(TreeReaderFactory.java:2004)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.orc.RecordReaderImpl.next(RecordReaderImpl.java:1044)
        ... 24 more
```

Comment: Your question needs formatting.

Comment: @Sidney I also ran into this issue.  Did you end up finding a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Set this in your code `hive.fetch.task.conversion=none`